# Setting up a secure back-end NodeJS server for multiple front-end domains

Tags: node.js, security, web, nginx, vps

I've been doing a lot of research recently on creating a backend for all the websites that I run and a few days ago I leased a VPS running Debian.

Long-term, I'd like to use it as the back-end for some web applications. However, these client-side javascript apps are running on **completely different domains** than the VPS domain. I was thinking about running the various back-end applications on the VPS as daemons. For example, daemon 1 is a python app, daemons 2 and 3 are node js, etc. I have no idea how many of these I might eventually create.

Currently, I only have a single NodeJS app running on the VPS. I want to implement two methods on it listening over some arbitrary port, port 4000 for example:

- /GetSomeData (GET request) - takes some params and serves back some JSON
- /AddSomeData (POST request) - takes some params and adds to a back-end MySQL db

These methods should only be useable from one specific domain (called DomainA) which is different than the VPS domain.

Now one issue that I feel I'm going to hit my head against is CORS policy. It sounds like I need to include a response header for Access-Control-Allow-Origin: DomainA. The problem is that in the future, I may want to add another acceptable requester domain, for example DomainB. What would I do then? Would I need to validate the incoming request.connection.remoteAddress, and if it matched DomainA/DomainB, write the corresponding Access-Control-Allow-Origin?

As of about 5 minutes ago before posting this question, I came across this from the [W3C site](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#resource-implementation):

> Resources that wish to enable themselves to be shared with multiple Origins but do not respond uniformly with "*" must in practice generate the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header dynamically in response to every request they wish to allow. As a consequence, authors of such resources should send a Vary: Origin HTTP header or provide other appropriate control directives to prevent caching of such responses, which may be inaccurate if re-used across-origins.

Even if I do this, I'm a little worried about security. By design anyone on my DomainA website can use the web app, you don't have to be a registered user. I'm concerned about attackers spoofing their IP address to be equal to DomainA. It seems like it wouldn't matter for the GetSomeData request since my NodeJS would then send the data back to DaemonA rather than the attacker. However, what would happen if the attackers ran a script to POST to AddSomeData a thousand times? I don't want my sql table being filled up by malicious requests.

On another note, I've been reading about [nginx](http://nginx.org/) and virtual hosts and how you can use them to establish different routes depending on the incoming domain but I don't *BELIEVE* that I need these things; however perhaps I'm mistaken.

Once again, I don't want to use the VPS as a web-site server, the Node JS listener is going to be returning some collection of JSON hence why I'm not making use of port 80. In fact the primary use of the VPS is to do some heavy manipulation of data (perhaps involving the local MySQL db) and then return a collection of JSON that any number of front-end client browser apps can use.

I've also read some recommendations about making use of NodeJS [Restify](http://mcavage.me/node-restify/) or [ExpressJS](http://expressjs.com/). Do I need these for what I'm trying to do?

Comment: What hosting provider are you using? AWS has a lot of tooling around securing your services to specific subnets etc. It basically all comes down to firewall rules and (potentially) routing. You could also just have completely open backend services and put an authentication layer (e.g. oauth2) in front of them.

Comment: @d11wtq Actually I'm on Linode. This is basically my first experience as a Linux system admin. Even if I did routing, wouldn't I still need some kind of authentication for the POST method? Is there any way for me to restrict incoming requests by source IP and guarantee that they aren't spoofing said IP?